# FInd dhcp servers on LAN

Tags: dhcp

i want to discover all the dhcp server currently available on LAN

Comment: If you want to do it in C#, we;ll help you move this to StackOverflow, which is where programming questions go.

Comment: i have posted it there too

Comment: Why don't you grab the source for DHCPDUMP and figure out how to port it it C#?

Comment: Probably you have only one DHCP server on your broadcast domain. I don't test having more than one but all of them might respond to [`sudo nmap --script broadcast-dhcp-discover`](https://superuser.com/a/1114078/500826).

Answer (score 1):

Try [DHCP Explorer](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Network-Tools/Network-IP-Scanner/DHCPExplorer.shtml), of course it'll only find servers on segments it's ran against, not 'all' as DHCP isn't routed by default.

Comment: i want to do it melodramatically using c# without being a part of the domain

Comment: Well domain has nothing to do with it, DHCP is a L2 function, you'll just have to find your interfaces and issue multiple DHCP requests, noting responders, that's your only option really.

Comment: If you want to do it without being in a domain, use Chopper's suggestion. It doesn't require it. If you want to do it in C#, we;ll help you move this to StackOverflow, which is where programming questions go. If you want to do it melodramatically, then, I dunno, make the output in all-caps with lots of !!!!! at the end.

Comment: Chopper can to guid me how send DHCP Request using c#????

Comment: :-) mfinni sorry it was "programatically" not "melodramatically"

Comment: I've found that DHCP Explorer only discovers the first DHCP server that responds. I've got two DHCP servers on my network (split scope) and DHCP Explorer never discovers both of them.

Comment: @mfinni - hahaha, @joeq - good point, well made, @Ehtsham - no, ask on the appropriate forum (read our FAQ please)

Comment: You'll want to read RFCs 2131 and 2132 and figure out how to handle non-IP packets using raw sockets.

Answer (score 1):

DHCP requests are limited to a broadcast domain - i.e. subnets delimited by routers, unless you have something like IP helper setup on the router.  So using some kind of network level discovery method, you will never know for sure if you got them all, unless you connect to every subnet.

You could use Wireshark or Network Monitor to view the network traffic in each of your broadcast domains - every DHCP server in a broadcast domain should respond to a DHCP request, even though the client will only handle the first response it recieves.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find DHCP servers using a windows client your can check out the MS toll dhcploc utility which is part of the Supports tools package. [XP SP2 Support Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=49ae8576-9bb9-4126-9761-ba8011fabf38&displaylang=en)